# Why omp version is slower than serial?

Tags: c++, concurrency, openmp

It's a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613297/one-lane-bridge-using-monitor)
Now I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>


#define max(a, b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b)

const int m = 2001;
const int n = 2000;
const int p = 4;

double v[m + 2][m + 2];
double x[m + 2];
double y[m + 2];
double _new[m + 2][m + 2];
double maxdiffA[p + 1];
int icol, jrow;

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(p);

    double h = 1.0 / (n + 1);

    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for private(icol) shared(x, y, v, _new)
    for (icol = 0; icol <= n + 1; ++icol) {
        x[icol] = y[icol] = icol * h;

        _new[icol][0] = v[icol][0] = 6 - 2 * x[icol];

        _new[n + 1][icol] = v[n + 1][icol] = 4 - 2 * y[icol];

        _new[icol][n + 1] = v[icol][n + 1] = 3 - x[icol];

        _new[0][icol] = v[0][icol] = 6 - 3 * y[icol];
    }


    const double eps = 0.01;


    #pragma omp parallel private(icol, jrow) shared(_new, v, maxdiffA)
    {
        while (true) { //for [iters=1 to maxiters by 2]
            #pragma omp single
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) maxdiffA[i] = 0;
            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    _new[icol][jrow] =
                            (v[icol - 1][jrow] + v[icol + 1][jrow] + v[icol][jrow - 1] + v[icol][jrow + 1]) / 4;
            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    v[icol][jrow] = (_new[icol - 1][jrow] + _new[icol + 1][jrow] + _new[icol][jrow - 1] +
                                     _new[icol][jrow + 1]) / 4;

            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    maxdiffA[omp_get_thread_num()] = max(maxdiffA[omp_get_thread_num()],
                                                         fabs(_new[icol][jrow] - v[icol][jrow]));

            #pragma omp barrier

            double maxdiff = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < p; ++k) {
                maxdiff = max(maxdiff, maxdiffA[k]);
            }


            if (maxdiff < eps)
                break;
            #pragma omp barrier
            //#pragma omp single
            //std::cout << maxdiff << std::endl;
        }
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("start = %.16lf\nend = %.16lf\ndiff = %.16lf\n", start, end, end - start);

    return 0;
}
```

But why it works 2-3 times slower (32sec vs 18sec) than serial analog:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

#define max(a,b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b)

const int m = 2001;
const int n = 2000;
double v[m + 2][m + 2];
double x[m + 2];
double y[m + 2];
double _new[m + 2][m + 2];

int main() {
    double h = 1.0 / (n + 1);

    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    for (int i = 0; i <= n + 1; ++i) {
        x[i] = y[i] = i * h;

        _new[i][0]=v[i][0] = 6 - 2 * x[i];

        _new[n + 1][i]=v[n + 1][i] = 4 - 2 * y[i];

        _new[i][n + 1]=v[i][n + 1] = 3 - x[i];

        _new[0][i]=v[0][i] = 6 - 3 * y[i];
    }

    const double eps=0.01;
    while(true){ //for [iters=1 to maxiters by 2]
        double maxdiff=0.0;
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                _new[i][j]=(v[i-1][j]+v[i+1][j]+v[i][j-1]+v[i][j+1])/4;
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                v[i][j]=(_new[i-1][j]+_new[i+1][j]+_new[i][j-1]+_new[i][j+1])/4;

        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                maxdiff=max(maxdiff, fabs(_new[i][j]-v[i][j]));

        if(maxdiff<eps) break;
        std::cout << maxdiff<<std::endl;
    }

    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("start = %.16lf\nend = %.16lf\ndiff = %.16lf\n", start, end, end - start);

    return 0;
}
```

Also interesting that it works SAME TIME as version (I can post it here if you say so) which looks like so

```
while(true){ //106 iteratins here!!!
#pragma omp paralell for
for(...)
#pragma omp paralell for
for(...)
#pragma omp paralell for
for(...)
}
```

But I thought that what making omp code slow is spawning threads inside while loop 106 times...  But no! Then probably threads simultaneously write to the same array cells.. But where does it happen? I don't see it could you show me please?
Maybe it's because too much barriers? But Lecturer told me to implement the code like so and "analyse it" Maybe the answer is "Jacobi algorithm isn't meant to run well in parallel"? Or it's just my lame coding?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question a few days ago?  You don't finish your homework by throwing out suggestions and leaving the obvious problems unsolved.

Comment: I was asked to post this one as a separate question So I did. If you know, could you please answer this question describing which exactly are "the obvious problems unsolved" ? That's the thing that I've spent several days trying to understand... And this code not to be slower than serial Shouldn't I "throw suggestions" when asking question? If suggestions are the the only thing I have No understanding why it's slow...

Comment: Ok I'll "try applying parallelism incrementally so as to see which loops are buggy."

Comment: The times you report are suspicious. How do you compile your code and on what system do you run it? With `g++8 -O3` it the serial/parallel versions take 1.65 / 1.45 s respectively on my desktop system. (NOTE: Always compare runtimes from compiler optimized versions)

Comment: wow @Zulan I also wonder why is that You measured time exactly with the same method " omp_get_wtime();"  ?! I mean you've read the timings from the programm's output?  I've been tearing off the hair on the head trying find the issue with code.. But the problem is that I run it on Windows under  Clion IDE  ? mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2\ compiler I'll try to compile it using comandline

Comment: On university cluster for sequental n=2000 I get:  
start = 23454418.3263293653726578  
end = 23454429.8953202702105045  
diff = 11.5689909048378468  
And OMP  n=2000 
start = 23454590.6604881882667542
end = 23454610.2112198658287525
diff = 19.5507316775619984

Comment: Hmm Quite interesting and shocking Compiling like so C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2\mingw64\bin>g++ -o "D:\Projects\BFU\6th Semestr\Parallel\4\Clion\mainOMP.exe" -fopenmp "D:\Projects\BFU\6th Semestr\Parallel\4\Clion\mainOMP.cpp" and running exe from compiler's directory (otherwise complaints about dll) I get  
start = 1527457308.6600000858306885
end = 1527457347.0150001049041748
diff = 38.3550000190734863
  Taskamanager says btw that the programm is taking 80-86% of my CPU... 
When I run serial analog  
...
diff = 19.8839998245239258

Comment: so  @Zulan I wonder how could you/I get such controversial results?

Comment: Use `-O3`, e.g. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am writing to make you aware of a few situations. It is not short to write in a comment, so I decided to write as an answer.

Every time a thread is made, it takes some time for its creation. if your program's running time in a single core is short, then the creation of threads will make this time longer for multi-core.

Plus using a barrier makes all your threads wait for others, which could somehow be slowed down in cpu. this way, even if all threads finish the job very fast, that last one will make the total run time longer.

Try to run your program with bigger sized arrays where time is around 2 minutes for single threading. then make your way to multi-core.

Then try to wrap your main code in a normal loop to run it a few times and prints the timings for each. the first run of the loop might be slow because of loading libraries, but the next runs should be faster to prove the increasing speed.

If above suggestions do not give a result, then it means your coding needs more editing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!! I'll try

Comment: 1) There is only one parallel region in the code, no re-creating threads. 2) Those loops are balanced, why do you suspect load balancing issues at the barriers (aport from the `single` obviously) 3) loading libraries doesn't typically take seconds

Comment: @Zulan, 1- every omp code creates threads to run parallel code 2- barriers are not balancers, they are checkpoints where every thread must finish their job before passing this point 3- you asking that? then you are just a rookie in parallezitation. real time jobs depends on operating systems whhere you have to wait for other programs too to load a library, even for mere kilobyte-program can take many seconds to load.

Comment: @Дмитрий, I see you accepted my suggested steps. would you please tell which one helped to solve the problem, and how are your results now?

Answer (score 0):

So the root of evel was

```
max(maxdiffA[w],fabs(_new[icol][jrow] - v[icol][jrow]))
```

because it's

```
#define max(a, b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b)
```

It's probably creating TOO much branching ('if's ) Without this thing parallel version works 8 times faster and loading CPU 68% instead of 99%..
The starange thing: same "max" doesn't affect serioal version